# Trying to use the spread operator with TypeScript and Object.assign

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assign some mapped values to an object like so:

```js
const sampleStrings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const sampleValues = sampleStrings.map(value => ({
  [value]: {
    name: 'bob',
  },
}));
const result = Object.assign(...sampleValues);

console.log(result)
```

However, I get the following error message:

> TS2557: Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.

[image]

I know that I should be doing something like

```
interface Foo {
  [x: string]: {
    name: string;
  };
}

const sampleStrings = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const sampleValues = sampleStrings.map(value => ({
  [value]: {
    name: 'bob',
  },
}));
const result = Object.assign(...sampleValues);
```

But I can't exactly figure out how my `Foo` interface should be configured. Also, what happens if I do not happen to know the length of my `sampleStrings` array, how would I fix this issue then?

Comment: You get that because an `Array.prototype.map` return type is `T[]` and it's impossible to infer from it that its size is at least 1.

Answer (score 1):

All the compiler actually knows about the type of `sampleValues` is that is of type `Array<Record<string, {name: string}>>`.  Such an array type can have any number of elements, including zero, so you can't spread it into a function taking at least one parameter without complaint.

The easiest way to deal with this is probably to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `sampleValues` is of a more specific type than it can infer.  To avoid the error all you need to do is pick a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type containing at least one element, but you can go further and be even more detailed:

```
const sampleValues = sampleStrings.map(value => ({
  [value]: {
    name: "bob"
  }
})) as [
  { foo: { name: string } },
  { bar: { name: string } },
  { baz: { name: string } }
];
```

Here we are saying that `sampleValue` will be a tuple of exactly three objects, each with one known key from `foo`, `bar`, or `baz`, and a value of type `{name: string}`.  That will now allow you to spread into `Object.assign()`:

```
const result = Object.assign(...sampleValues); // okay
// const result: {foo: {name: string}} & {bar: {name: string}} & {baz: {name: string}}
```

and the type of `result` is known to be an intersection type similar to `{foo: {name: string}, bar: {name: string}, baz: {name: string}}`.

This is my suggested solution, I think.

---

You could *try* to tell the compiler that `sampleStrings` is an n-tuple (using, for example, a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions)), and that mapping over an n-tuple produces another n-tuple (using, for example, [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)) like this:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  map<U>(cb: (val: T) => U): { [K in keyof this]: U };
}

const sampleStrings = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const;

const sampleValues = sampleStrings.map(value => ({
  [value]: {
    name: "bob"
  }
}));
const result = Object.assign(...sampleValues);
/* const result: {
    [x: string]: {
        name: string;
    };
} */
```

And this will prevent the `Object.assign()` error, but when you're done you still end up with a pretty weakly typed object for `result`... and the more work you put into trying to get the compiler to *infer* a better type, the less clear the code becomes.  So I'd probably recommend against trying to make the compiler smarter about what's happening here, and instead use some well-chosen type assertions to make the compiler's job easier rather than harder.  It's not as type safe (since you can always be wrong about what you assert) but it's cleaner code, in my opinion.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBAymgogJQCoEkB5AOTSQG8AoJJeAe2CgBckpwYAbCNJgJwEtgAcyhIAvEgDaAIgBmdOtIA0SaQCMQvZao0AvaQF0A3NVoNmrdlwBqIDgFdo4y2E7c+gkQDowIGAAoANztHcQA+JH8qGhpJYIcIAwAuClMYpFBIFPU6NWk0pABfU0KASlKkEFFJAvIkeToUusyIFOYBYSKipVqkDV4mjPBW1g9Owu7evUGWtrGhLuKaY1N6RhZeaHsOFglCNQArCHgmLyqofiFgfy9btlcbEOhSoyQAejekOgBrEABPUwfMzrJCbKDbJhNBpNWajDpCQoTABkFH6MOGc3hiKQKPI0wosPankRlGKlEoQIAIpgAMIAGRQ2BQBBISAAsjgAOL4YicpLkwRMCC8WQIZDYCAgAAmDA4fxQvF4-wAPLgItEkL4YMqAKphfzwNQpIJ2FK4CpiCI60qDSQAaSQgiQ3wgfzosiQTAAFvwoMkkDqiiYyWsLPc3Dx4aIJDIGtp1Jp43pDJVRKGmCZKOmXG5bAlozmuJHPFAfH4TQlwpENXEnv6NTRYTk8iVSeUTNmwRDnPsjiczlALlcbncrBA844oC8KQAqYEWLs7JoFSQAD0xnnrBXShPmJnShWDSBnb0oQA)